# Transitivity of normality in $H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft H_2 \triangleleft H_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

> Supposing that  $H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft H_2 \triangleleft H_3$ , $H_0 \triangleleft  H_3$ and $H_3 / H_0 $ is abelian. Prove that  $H_0 \triangleleft  H_i$ and $H_i \triangleleft  H_3$ for $i=1,2$.

**My attempt**

I thought that if $H_0=\{e\}$, then $H_3$ is abelian, and then the conclusion is trivial.

But I got stuck on the general cases. Could you please give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ThomasShelby I'm not quite familiat with that, but I know that concept.

Comment: Won't the correspondence principle give this immediately? Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal. So given $H_0\le K\le H_3$, $H_0\unlhd H_3$, $H_3/H_0$ abelian, it follows that $H_0\unlhd K$ and $K\unlhd H_3$. All because $K\unlhd H_3$ if and only if $K/H_0\unlhd H_3/H_0$ and the latter is trivial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen whoops, I got it! Thanks for your lighting words

Comment: Glad to hear you got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim follows from the correspondence principle. Actually, given that $H_3/H_0$ is abelian, it follows that $K\unlhd H_0$ for any intermediate group $K$, $H_3\le K\le H_0$. All because $K\unlhd H_0$ if and only if $K/H_0\unlhd H_3/H_0$, and the latter is obcious.